# Update different columns depending on values from a another table in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a requirement like below.

I have a table with all chars put in one column and i need to use the information create a table that has one olumn for each char.

Example:
**Source table:**

```
article id | char id | char value
1          | 1       | book
1          | 2       | yes
1          | 3       | 100
2          | 1       | cd
2          | 2       | No
```

**Destination Table**

```
article id | type | lendable | number of pages 
1          | book | yes      | 100
2          | cd   | no       | NULL
```

we can do this with two inner joins but if there are more columns then i will be difficult. Is there a straight forward way of doing this??

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: and I think you mean `INSERT` not `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be simply done using `INSERT INTO..SELECT`.

```
INSERT INTO destinationTable(articleid, type, lendable, NumberOfPages)
SELECT  ArticleID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN charID = 1 THEN charValue END) type,
        MAX(CASE WHEN charID = 2 THEN charValue END) lendable,
        MAX(CASE WHEN charID = 3 THEN charValue END) NumberOfPages
FROM    SourceTable 
GROUP   BY ArticleID
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than build a single fancy query that "does it all", it's simpler and clearer to create separate small queries - one for each type of update.

Doing so has these benefits:

- better maintenance - adding another new type of custom mapping, or changing an existing one is easy
- it's much clearer and easy to understand - clarity is the cornerstone of good programming
- testing is much easier because your change set is smaller and cohesive

Answer (score 0):

You can use **pivot** or **Max(value)..Group by** to 'pivot' your table, then use **Insert into select..** or **Select * into...**
**[PIVOT SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/75b89/3)**

```
with CTE_SourceTable
as 
(
  select article_id, [1] as type, [2] as lendable, [3] as [number of pages]
  from SourceTable
  pivot
  (
    max(char_value)
    for char_id in ([1],[2],[3])
   ) as PVT
)
select * 
into DestinationTable 
from CTE_SourceTable
```

**[Max(value)..Group By SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7877f/2)**

```
with CTE_SourceTable
as 
(
  select article_id, [1] as type, [2] as lendable, [3] as [number of pages]
  from SourceTable
  pivot
  (
    max(char_value)
    for char_id in ([1],[2],[3])
   ) as PVT
)
select *
into DestinationTable
from CTE_SourceTable
```